# Shell script to change uid for user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-scripting

I have a file (users_uid) with users and uid are two parameters as given below  :

```
    assds  611
    dsdsd  612
    xyzx   613
    rerer  614
```

These users exist in the machine. I want to change the uid of each user to that value given right for the username. I know that I can modify the uid using `usermod -u <uid> <user>`. But I don't know how to read the two values in the file and put them as the 2 parameters in a **for** loop with usermod command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk '{print "usermod -u "$2" "$1}' users_uid | bash

Comment: Thanks It worked ! But the sed is not required i think.  # cat  users_uid |awk '{print "usermod -u "$2" "$1}' | bash

Comment: Sed it required in case the first line is like in your example `users  uid`. Otherwise it isn't required.

Comment: @nitins: if the users_uid file doesn't contain column name (the first line), no need to use `cat`: `awk '{ print "usermod -u "$2" "$1 }' users_uid | bash`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I actually don't have that line. Just added here to make it clear

Comment: I've removed that line to make it clear that the "header" is not actually in the file.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer runs the risk of executing malicious or accidental content in the data file. Here is the correct way to do what you want without spawning `awk` and an additional copy of `bash` plus it's safe from the risk I mentioned.

```
while read -r user uid
do
    usermod -u "$user" "$uid"
done < users_uid
```

As a one-liner:

```
while read -r user uid; do usermod -u "$user" "$uid"; done < users_uid
```